# Abrir um calendário em um AlertDialog e salvar a data escolhida

Tags: android

Estou criando um app e preciso que, em um componente `EditText`, quando eu clicar nele, apareça um calendário (pensei em colocar em um `AlertDialog` por causa dos botões de adicionar e cancelar, mas se alguém tiver uma ideia melhor agradeço se compartilhar).

A pessoa escolheria uma data, a data ficaria no `EditText` em forma de "dd/mm/aaaa", e essa data seria salva mais tarde no Banco de Dados nesse formato.

Eu tenho um layout com um `CalendarView`, a classe que acompanha o layout, e essa classe, quando clicada em uma data, levaria para outra classe que capturaria essa data:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Long dateSelected = intent.getLongExtra("dataLongMiliseconds", 0);
Date date = new Date(dateSelected);
```

O problema é que não estou sabendo programar isso em um fragment onde contém um formulário onde está o `EditText` da data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faz o seguinte no fragmento que está o seu editText crie um Listener pra ele e incializa o calendário como a seguir:

```
   seuEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

         final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(SuaActivity.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                            calendar.set(year, month, day);
                            String format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH);
                            Date date;

                            try {
                                date = sdf.parse(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
                                String dayS = new SimpleDateFormat("dd", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);
                                String monthS = new SimpleDateFormat("MM", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);
                                String yearS = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);

                                seuEditText.setText((dayS + "/" + monthS + "/" + yearS));
                            } catch (ParseException ignored) {

                            }
                        }
                    }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker();
        }

            }
        });
```

E para recuperar o texto no edittext:

```
seuEditText.getText().toString();
```

Espero que isso lhe ajude. Qualquer dúvida só me chamar.

**UPDATE:**

Para trocar o tema de cores do `datepickerdialog` faça o seguinte, na pasta res/values/styles , crie um style:

```
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorAccent">#F1C46B</item>
    </style>
```

E então no código passado acima, quando você inicializa um novo DatePickerDialog, coloque esse tema depois do context, e antes do OnDateSetListener(), assim:

```
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new  DatePickerDialog(SuaActivity.this, 
             R.style.DialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        .
        .
        .
```

O Exemplo desse tema altera a cor padrão do Dialog, mas é possível também, alterar outras cores, por exemplo:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorAccent">#ff6d00</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#33691e</item>
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">#8E61DF</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#d50000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Funcionou, amigo?

Comment: Funcionou certinho amigo, obrigado de verdade! Só tenho uma dúvidas, tipo, existe alguma forma de eu personalizar (tipo a cor por exemplo) o calendário que aparece pra mim? Ou programar uma opção pra as pessoas personalizarem?

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta, é simples pra alterar algumas cores. Daria também pro usuário alterar as cores, mas aí é mais abrangente a programação, e com base nesse meu exemplo é possível fazer.

Comment: Muito obrigado! :)